# How to set request.getParameter in jsp:setProperty

Tags: jsp, javabeans, http-request-parameters

I used beans/form processing to take input parameters on login screen and then with those parameters try and log the user into the application.

However I am getting an error-

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /loginbean.jsp(6,59) Attribute value request.getParameter("userName") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the val

The line of code which has this error is the second line in the block of code given below-
(ie line of code for the property with name='userName')

`loginbean.jsp`

```
<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean" >
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
  <jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
 </jsp:useBean>
```

`LoginBean.java`

```
package logbean;
public class LoginBean {
  String userName="";
  String password="";
  public String getUserName() {
  return userName;
  }
  public void setUsername(String username) {
  this.userName = userName;
  }
  public String getPassword() {
  return password;
  }
  public void setPassword(String password) {
 this.password = password;
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here,

```xml
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
```

you're attempting to mix *scriptlets* and taglibs. This is invalid. Use the one or the other. When the `userName` would contain a doublequote like `foo"bar` then the value of the JSP tag will basically end up like `value="foo"bar"`. This is syntactically invalid.

Since *scriptlets* is a [dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) technology, I'd suggest to just get rid of it altogether. The proper way would be to use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). In EL, all request parameters are available as a `Map<String, String>` through the implicit variable `${param}`. Make use of it.

```xml
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="${param.userName}"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="${param.password}"/>
```

Alternatively, you can also let JSP automagically set all properties as below when all parameter names are the same as property names anyway:

```xml
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="*"/>
```