# simple error due to use of double quotes in a jsp file

Tags: jsp, escaping, double-quotes

I have the following line of code in a JSP File in my web app that is giving an error:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
```

The error message that I get is:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   /loginbean.jsp(6,59) Attribute value
>   request.getParameter("userName") is
>   quoted with " which must be escaped
>   when used within the value

What I read on some sites is that characters like `'` (single quote) or `"` (double quote) need to be prefixed with an escape sequence `\` (backslash) if they are to be used.

However, when I try and prefix the double quotes (around the word userName) with backslash, I immediately get the following error- "Illegal Character \92- Unclosed String Literal"

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: You have already asked this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494283/error-in-beans-form-processing-using-jsp-files-in-java-web-application If you cannot seem to find your asked questions back, please click on the link behind your username in the top navigation bar. It leads to your user profile where you can see all your previously asked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/793999/arvind

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should use single quotes on the `value` parameter, ie:

```
value='<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>'
```

or set the `org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING` parameter to `false` as described here:

http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2009/10/strict-quote-escaping-in-tomcat/

Comment: I tried with single quotes- I am getting the following error now- org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Can't find a method to write property 'userName' of type 'java.lang.String' in a bean of type 'logbean.LoginBean'

Comment: Set also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878326/passing-environment-variable-to-ant-task-without-ant-opts on how to set this for jasper ant task

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Tomcat 8.5+, the property `org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false`
will not be acknowledged.

I was able to set the property successfully in `{TOMCAT_ROOT}/conf/web.xml` by adding the following within the `<servlet>` block:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>strictQuoteEscaping</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: By default, there are two `servlet` elements in `web.xml`. You need to place the above `init-param` element in the `<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>`

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to modify your JSPs, just set:

```
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```

in your `{TOMCAT_ROOT}/conf/catalina.properties` file. Works like a charm!

Kudos [from here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45015#c19).

Answer (score 6):

This can be fixed with a IDE Regexp Replace:

```
(<\w+:(?:[^>]|<%=[^%]+%>)+=)"([^<"]*<%=[^%]*"[^%]*%>[^"]*)"
```

For the replacement text, enter:

$1'$2'

Comment: +1 Pretty impressive.  Not readable or anything, but impressive.

Comment: instead of replacing with single quotes, I want to replace with escaping the inner double-quotes. what should be my regex and replacement text here.

Comment: I have gained a lot of time ! It what i was looking for !

Comment: @thiru_k had the same issue, here is a regex for future reference `(?<=<%=.*)(?!\\)"(?=.*%>)` replacing with `\\"`

Answer (score 1):

The example looks like a XSS example! This is a security vulnerability.
I suggest to put in place a html encoding library like c:out tag or http://owasp-esapi-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk_doc/latest/org/owasp/esapi/Encoder.html#encodeForHTMLAttribute%28java.lang.String%29

I also suggest to take the userName from an authenticated session and not form the request param if possible (unless this is a login/registration form only!)

Answer (score 0):

if you use a " as scriplet delimeter, you can't use the some as a property delimiter in getParameter. So change the delimeter of scriptlet by '.As it tag parameter, I think there 'll be no problem. Otherwise replace :

value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>

by :

value='<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>'/>

Answer (score 0):

I case Jasper JSP validation phase is used during project build.

Since Tomcat 8 there is a new attribute [strictQuoteEscaping](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration) for Ant task and a switch [-no-strictQuoteEscaping](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/constant-values.html#org.apache.jasper.JspC.SWITCH_NO_STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING) for running [org.apache.jasper.JspC](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc8.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/jasper/JspC.java) from command line.