# Passing environment variable to ant task, without ANT_OPTS

Tags: ant, environment-variables

I'm calling the Jasper ant task, and I want to set the `org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING` environment variable.  I can set ANT_OPTS to be `-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false` and it works correctly. However, I want a setting I can put into the build.xml, so I don't need to tell my teammates that they need to set ANT_OPTS.

I've tried

```
<property name="env.org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING" 
    value="false"/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I pass an environment variable to an ant task?

EDIT: By "doesn't work", I mean I get an error saying an attribute `is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value`
  If I set it via ANT_OPTS, I do not get this error.

Comment: explain "doesn't work".  Did you see string quote escaping in japer?  I ask because the property value is try in the code block of your question but false in the text portion.

Comment: I fixed the XML, and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `<property>` task to define an environmental prefix:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

Now, you can simply prepend `env.` to your environment variable and treat it like an already defined Ant property:

```
 <property environment="env"/>
 <echo message="My path is &quot;${env.PATH}&quot;"/>
```

Comment: I'm probably being thick - but I don't see how this helps setting this env variable so that the JspC taskdef will pick it up?

Comment: Your question was _How can I pass an environment variable to an ant task?_. By using this, the value of that environment variable is now an Ant property and can be used in Ant tasks. If there is something else going on, you need to explain it. What does your `<taskdef/>` look like? What is your error message. What line is it on, and what _task_ is on that line?