# Spring Form mismatched tag error

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following (opening) spring form tag

```
<form:form action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/register") %>" class = "form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am getting a 500 error when I try to run the application:

```
/WEB-INF/view/registration/register.jsp(50,24) Attribute value  blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/register")  is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
```

Any idea what the problem is with my tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes in the action because you're using double quotes inside the parenthesis.

```
action='<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/register") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message points you directly to the issue: Yo have double quotes inside and outside your template, which generates some parsing errors.

You can fix it by simply using single quotes on the outside, like:

```
<form:form action='<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/register") %>' class = "form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Edit:

Also probably duplicate of [simple error due to use of double quotes in a jsp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501265/simple-error-due-to-use-of-double-quotes-in-a-jsp-file)